# Remove items from a Pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas datasets:

```
import pandas
csv1 = pandas.read_csv('test10', sep='\t')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('test11', sep='\t')
```

How to remove from `csv1` the rows that have a `blah` field which is already present in `csv2`?

---

Example:

```
#csv1
id blah
1  abc
2  def
3  ghi
4  xyz

#csv2
data1 blah
69236 abz
9623  ghi
6152  def
```

Then the output should be:

```
id blah
1  abc
4  xyz
```

Indeed rows 2 and 3 have to removed from `csv1` because their `blah` field is present in `csv2`'s `blah` column.

Comment: Downvoter, please can you explain how to improve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go like this:

```
csv1 = csv1[~csv1['blah'].isin(csv2['blah'])]
```

Comment: Does `~` mean not?

Comment: Yes, it inverts the boolean mask after the symbol :)